# Error : NullPointerException a null object reference (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Tengo un proyecto en `Android` en el cual envío el valor de una variable desde un `Adapter` a un `Activity` asi:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent inicioIntent = new Intent(context, Activity2.class);
inicioIntent.putExtra("idU", idUser);
context.startActivity(inicioIntent);}
```

Y en la Activity lo recibo asi:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
idGestor = intent.getExtras().getString("idG");}
```

Entonces del **Activity** paso al **Activity2**, pero cuando regreso se detiene la app y me marca error justo en la linea donde recibo el valor de la variable.

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'java.lang.String
>   android.os.BaseBundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object
>   reference

Supongo que lo marca porque no estoy enviando el valor desde el **Activity2** al **Activity**, sino del **Adapter** al **Activity**, pero se supone que ese valor ya debe de existir.

Comment: Para entender mejor : Al presionar el boton de atras se vuelve a ejecutar el mismo activity? Si es el caso tendrias que sobreescribir el siguiente método: @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
...
} En la cual podrás utilizar finish() por ejemplo para terminar el activity actual. Saludos.

Comment: Hola, de la Activity2 al Activity1 regreso utilizando finish(), e igual se detiene con onBackPressed()

Comment: @Geek me parece que tienes un error en la forma de obtener los datos, el método onCreate de Activity2 es solo lo que agregaste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo unico que debes hacer es estos dos pasos:

1.- Validar que el parametro que pases no este nulo ya que al ir a otra actividad supongo que ejecutas el metodo finish(), entonces cada que vuelves a esta actividad intenta consumir esta variable y como esta nulo, te generara error.

Puedes validar colocando:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
   if(bundle !=null){
      idGestor = bundle.getString("idG");  
   } 
}
```

2.- Debes enviar desde el activity2 en el evento onback el parametro idG

```
@Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
   Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity.class);
   intent.putExtra("idG", idG);
   startActivity(intent)
   finish();
 }
```

3.- Algo que no estoy seguro es que en tu metodo de adapter llamas el parametro:idU

```
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent inicioIntent = new Intent(context, Activity2.class);
inicioIntent.putExtra("idU", idUser);
context.startActivity(inicioIntent);}
```

Pero en tu activity2 quieres recuperar el parametro con el nombre idG

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     idGestor = intent.getExtras().getString("idG");
}
```

No deberia ser asi si fuera el caso en realidad?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
idGestor = intent.getExtras().getString("idU");}
```

Answer (score 1):

En `MainActivity2` debes realizar lo siguiente, agregar `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` y además validar la recepción del `bundle`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 Bundle parametros = this.getIntent().getExtras();
 if(parametros !=null){
    idGestor = parametros.getString("idG");  
 } 

}
```